# Biblatex not showing shortauthor when listing @online ressources in reference list?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I use biblatex with authoryear-icomp style and my MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}    

\usepackage[
style=authoryear-icomp,
isbn=false,
pagetracker=true,
firstinits=false,
maxbibnames=50,
maxcitenames=3,
mincitenames=1,
autocite=inline,
block=space,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=three+,
date=short,
backend=biber,
uniquename=false, 
uniquelist=false,
dashed=false,
sorting=nyt,
bibencoding=utf8
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{general.bib}
@book{bundesamt_fur_sicherheit_in_der_informationstechnik_bsi_it-grundschutzkataloge_2016,
    location = {Bonn},
    edition = {13. Ergänzungslieferung},
    title = {{IT}-Grundschutzkataloge},
    author = {{BSI (Bundesamt für Sicherheit in der Informationstechnik) }},
    shortauthor = {BSI},
    date = {2016},
}
@online{ibm,
author ={{International Business Machines Corporation}},
shortauthor = {{IBM}},
title = {2015 Cost of Data Breach Study},
year = {2015},
url = {http://www-03.ibm.com/security/data-breach/},
urldate = {2016-06-30},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{general.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{% BOOK --> C:\texlive\2015\texmf-dist\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\standard.bbx
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  {\printtext{\textbf
        {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}}}}
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \iffieldundef{author}
    {}
    {\newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{% Online --> C:\texlive\2015\texmf-dist\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\standard.bbx
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  {\printtext{\textbf
        {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}}}}
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Einleitung}
\section*{}
@online ressource: \textcite[][]{bundesamt_fur_sicherheit_in_der_informationstechnik_bsi_it-grundschutzkataloge_2016}
\section*{}
@book ressource: \textcite[][]{ibm}

\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\printbibliography[title={Literaturverzeichnis}]


\end{document}
```

My Problem is that biblatex prints the shortauthor field as expected when listing books in the list of references. But when citing @online ressources the shortauthor field is ignored, although the same bibmacro is used. Finally i want it to look like this and it's working but only for books:

[image]

For online ressource the shortauthor field is ignored:

[image]

How can I change that? Any help would be really much appreciated! Sry when I left out some things but I'm pretty much a beginner in writing with latex!

THX

Comment: Can you add a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) so that we already have some bib entries to play around with? Then you can explain what you want in the example.

Comment: yes, i'm currently working on it! thx

Comment: added a working MWE. Hope anyone can help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you. You will find that `biblatex` *does not* add the `shortauthor` field even for book entries, it just seems like that with your first example because you have `author = {{BSI (Bundesamt für Sicherheit in der Informationstechnik)}}`.

Comment: Me idiot! Thank you sir! I totally overlooked that... Sometime things are easier than expected! However that stupid failure led me to register here and learn how to give a MWE. So finally it was worth doing it...

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to modify the drivers, just use the [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{author}{\begingroup\bfseries}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{author}
  {\printnames{author}}
  {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}
     {\printnames{author}}
     {\printnames{shortauthor}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printnames{author}}}}
  {}{}
\xapptobibmacro{author}{\endgroup}{}{}

\xpretobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\begingroup\bfseries}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:editor}
  {\printnames{editor}}
  {\ifnameundef{shorteditor}
     {\printnames{editor}}
     {\printnames{shorteditor}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printnames{editor}}}}
  {}{}
\xapptobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\endgroup}{}{}

\xpretobibmacro{bbx:translator}{\begingroup\bfseries}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:translator}
  {\printnames{translator}}
  {\ifnameundef{shorttranslator}
     {\printnames{translator}}
     {\printnames{shorttranslator}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printnames{translator}}}}
  {}{}
\xapptobibmacro{bbx:translator}{\endgroup}{}{}
```

With this code we add the `short<name>` fields is available and then wrap the `<name>` in brackets. Furthermore the label is written in bold.

In total

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}    

\usepackage[
style=authoryear-icomp,
isbn=false,
pagetracker=true,
firstinits=false,
maxbibnames=50,
maxcitenames=3,
mincitenames=1,
autocite=inline,
block=space,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=three+,
date=short,
backend=biber,
uniquename=false, 
uniquelist=false,
dashed=false,
sorting=nyt,
bibencoding=utf8
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{general.bib}
@book{bundesamt_fur_sicherheit_in_der_informationstechnik_bsi_it-grundschutzkataloge_2016,
    location = {Bonn},
    edition = {13. Ergänzungslieferung},
    title = {{IT}-Grundschutzkataloge},
    author = {{Bundesamt für Sicherheit in der Informationstechnik}},
    shortauthor = {BSI},
    date = {2016},
}
@online{ibm,
author ={{International Business Machines Corporation}},
shortauthor = {{IBM}},
title = {2015 Cost of Data Breach Study},
year = {2015},
url = {http://www-03.ibm.com/security/data-breach/},
urldate = {2016-06-30},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{general.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{author}{\begingroup\bfseries}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{author}
  {\printnames{author}}
  {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}
     {\printnames{author}}
     {\printnames{shortauthor}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printnames{author}}}}
  {}{}
\xapptobibmacro{author}{\endgroup}{}{}

\xpretobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\begingroup\bfseries}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:editor}
  {\printnames{editor}}
  {\ifnameundef{shorteditor}
     {\printnames{editor}}
     {\printnames{shorteditor}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printnames{editor}}}}
  {}{}
\xapptobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\endgroup}{}{}

\xpretobibmacro{bbx:translator}{\begingroup\bfseries}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:translator}
  {\printnames{translator}}
  {\ifnameundef{shorttranslator}
     {\printnames{translator}}
     {\printnames{shorttranslator}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printnames{translator}}}}
  {}{}
\xapptobibmacro{bbx:translator}{\endgroup}{}{}



\begin{document}

\chapter{Einleitung}
\section*{}
@online ressource: \textcite[][]{bundesamt_fur_sicherheit_in_der_informationstechnik_bsi_it-grundschutzkataloge_2016}
\section*{}
@book ressource: \textcite[][]{ibm}

\clearpage

\printbibliography[title={Literaturverzeichnis}, heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why have you used `xpatch`? I was thinking to do a similar thing with `\renewbibmacro`, is it not sufficient? Just for curiosity...

Comment: @CarLaTeX I didn't want to copy the lengthy definitions of `bbx:editor`, `bbx:translator` for those changes. Normally I prefer a `\renewbibmacro` approach, but that can involve copying around lots of code for fairly minor changes in which case I prefer `xpatch`.